# Is there any way to use Tbitmap in background thread in FIREMONKEY?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Is there any way to use Tbitmap in background thread under delphi berlin and **Firemonkey** ? i just need the tbitmap to load a png, resize it and do some FillText in it, to finally later in the main thread draw it on the form canvas. i need this only for windows as i already found a way out on ios/android/macos

Comment: What was the method used for the other operating systems, and why does it not work for windows?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8710036/4997

Comment: @gabr before to make the question duplicate and close it can you ask  before to do so, question like "is this question is not a duplicate of ... ?" .. i say on Firemonkey and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708312/how-to-perform-an-image-stream-preview-to-a-delphi-6-frame-or-form-from-a-backgr/8710036#8710036 is for VCL and the question is 5 years old :( The answer from arnaud boucher is that "AFAIK TBitmap are thread-safe, if you work only on its canvas" and it's exactly the total opposite in firemonkey.

Comment: @Dsm because on android and ios i don't use Tbitmap but i use TTexture (the canvas, who is an openGL canvas, permit us to draw texture) and i updated the source code of delphi to make texture multi-thread. but under Windows it's not openGL so i m force to work with TBitmap.

Comment: It's not a dupe of that VCL question. If I were you I'd use WIC for this. Unlike Emba, who seem incapable of making a threadsafe bitmap component, MS can manage it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ... thanks david, but did you already work with wic under delphi ? i will need some wrapper i think ?

Comment: I don't know. It's a COM interface. It's probably quite involved.

Comment: @Vyacheslav How do you achieve this on Android and iOS? Documentation doesn't state any ability to draw anything on texture for any platform). Are you perhaps using some special OpenGL based code? If you are then all you should do is find equivalent code for DirectX since FMX is using DirectX on Windows instead of OpenGL.

Comment: @SilverWarior: under android / ios, I first draw the png on a Java bitmap (and equivalent on ios), After these plateform gave us all the tools we need to manipulate the bitmap (draw text, etc..). When i finish with the java/ios bitmap (all in background thread), i convert these bitmaps to Texture (with the help of TbitmapSurface). All of this inside the background thread, work like a charm! but didn't find yet any equivalent on windows :(

Comment: @Vyacheslav I see. So you were using methods native for each platform for your image manipulations on Android and iOS. I don't think Windows have any native support for this. Well not without using DirectX. Any way after looking at FMX TBitmap class I don't see why you could not use it in background thread. But to be sure about this I strongly recommend you post this question on official Embarcadero forums.

Comment: @SilverWarior. i confirm you the Tbitmap is not multithread (see https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14140 ) Normally in next release of delphi it is planned to make it multithread but i have no view about it

Comment: @Vyacheslav According to that bug report there is no information on when or in which Delphi version will this be fixed. So I'm afraid that for now your only bet is to find some Windows based image editing library. Perhaps Graphics32 library would offer you what you need for now.

Comment: @SilverWarior thanks ... i will make a try with Graphics32 but i m just affraid that graphic32 will not permit me to draw text of the image :(